# Why does grep ignore the leading '.'?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

I am trying to find a string in a web page downloaded w/ `curl`. I am using `grep` to find the string matching a *regular expression* pattern.

Following is the string I am trying to find:

```
./download/file.php?id=86753
```

This string is **part of** this larger string in the webpage:

```
href="./download/file.php?id=86753"
```

The `grep` incantation I'm working with is as follows:

```bash
grep -Eo '\.\/download\/file\.php\?id=[0-9]+' dlfile.html
```

But this finds **nothing** in the html file. However, if I modify `grep` as follows, I get two (2) matches. The **first match** is the one I need; the second is a useless distraction, and must not be included:

```bash
grep -Eo '\/download\/file\.php\?id=[0-9]+' dlfile.html
/download/file.php?id=86753
/download/file.php?id=62517
```

The string containing the second (undesired) match is as follows:

```
href="https://web.archive.org/web/20190824162104/https://www.somewhere.com/forums/download/file.php?id=62517&amp;sid=907ab04af81e19ad758c5bcf8ebdca32"
```

It seems the problem is w/ failure to recognize the leading `.` (dot) in the string. Note that this is the key difference between the desired string, and the undesired string.

##### Q: Why does this not work, and what do I need instead??

---

My environment: Debian derivative (Raspberry Pi), 'bullseye' release

Which `grep` & `bash` am I using?

```bash
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.6
...
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.1.4(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)
```

Comment: I think it all boils down to that you are escaping the slashes `/`, which don't need escaping, *backslashes* `\ ` are the ones that need to be escaped. (GNU) `grep` 3.11 gives me a warning: `grep: warning: stray \ before /`.

Comment: No need to backwhack `\/` forward slashes.  Please show us `grep -Eo '....../download/file\.php\?id=[0-9]+' | hexdump -C` output. (Sometimes it's spelled [hd](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump).) I'm concerned that it's a UTF-8 document with an "invisible" or "combining" character in there. While you're at it, reveal web server headers with `curl -i $URL` to verify we see a unicode header of `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`, and/or use `file *.html` or even `iconv` to check on charset details.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, both of your matched strings do not contain a leading `.` character.

Comment: The `-o` option is not helping here.  It makes your sample output confusing, especially since you didn't include any excerpts from the sample input.

Comment: I can't replicate this, I tried `printf 'href="./download/file.php?id=86753"' > test.txt; grep -Eo '\.\/download\/file\.php\?id=[0-9]+' test.txt` and it works fine for me on Ubuntu 22.04 GNU grep 3.7. The whole string is matched.

Comment: The reason it's returning nothing is because you're trying to match a string that does not exist in the web page

Comment: yes, exactly. The only place I can see `86753` appear is in the string `href="https://forums.raspberrypi.com/download/file.php?id=86753`.

Comment: "_that's because the grep I used did not contain the \. term._" - yes it did, @Seamus. The problem is that the text you're searching does not contain this character, but your pattern required it

Comment: @Seamus, it's not just Chris. I took the raw file link from that pastebin page and looked into it, the only part that remotely matches is the one that says `href="https://forums.raspberrypi.com/download/file.php?id=86753"`. (I ran  `curl -s https://pastebin.com/raw/BDegguyM | grep -Eo 'href=".*/download/file.php\?id=86753"'` and checked from the view on pastebin.) There's no substring `./download` there. You possibly have the wrong file, or some other tool you're using to view the page turns the links into relative links. (Or something else turned them into absolute links before uploading.)

Comment: Please don't include links (or images) in your question as that just makes it much harder for us to help you. In this case your pastebin link has expired so we can't see whatever it was you wanted us to see there.

Comment: Saemus @ChrisDavies is trying to help you fix your question. Right now it's an unanswerable jumble of snippets of text and broken links and claims of behavior that multiple people have attempted to but can't reproduce. Yes, parsing HTML with regexps is fragile but you didn't ask for help parsing HTML - you asked why your `grep` command can't match a specific string, the fact that that string is embedded somewhere in an HTML file that we cant see is irrelevant and if you thought otherwise you should have included some HTML as the sample input in your question instead of just a couple of strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been a lot of comments here. A couple of them raised valid concerns & questions. I believe I've finally unraveled the issue, and I'm posting that here in an effort to provide closure.

As you may have gathered, I was "scraping" a URL for a string containing an item of information that I needed. I developed a script to "automate" this task ~ maybe 2 years ago, and it's worked flawlessly. The script does two primary things:

1. `curl` & `grep` the webpage
2. take other action on the basis of the `grep` result

*"Something changed"* a few days ago. My "reliable" script began throwing an error during each run; the error indication suggested that `grep` was failing to find the string. The `grep` I was using:

```bash
curl blah-blah | grep -o '\.\/download\/file\.php?id.[0-9]*'
```

As of now, I still don't know all that has changed. I believe that one of the changes is the website has been outsourced to an outfit called "CloudFlare"; another seems to be that they no longer handle `curl` downloads the same way they handle downloads from a browser. Additional changes seem to be taking place.

The confusion reflected in my question is due in part to these website changes, **but is due mostly to me**. I should have been patient, and investigated the error more thoroughly before posting a question. My apologies to all involved.

One thing I'll claim to have learned from this experience: **`grep` is not the correct tool for parsing HTML**. I have two references to share:

1. This [*controversial* thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/22595851) from SO re using regexes to parse HTML
2. This [informative post from Hiks Gerganov](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/shell-html-get-text-between-tags) titled "HTML Parsing for Extracting Text Between HTML Tags in the Shell".

Answer (score 0):

You've used `grep -E`, requiring Extended Regular Expressions (EREs). Dot must always be escaped as a literal. Question mark is valid operator for an EREs so to match as a literal it also must be escaped:

```
echo 'href="./download/file.php?id=86753"' |
    grep -Eo '\./download/file.php\?id=[0-9]+'
```

You asked,

> Why does grep ignore the leading '.'?

> It seems the problem is w/ failure to recognize the leading . (dot) in the string.

Your pattern matches and requires a literal dot (that's what `\.` means). However, the string you've described in your question does not appear in the web page you're trying to search. `grep` doesn't ignore it; it mandates it. Look:

```
xmlstarlet format --html BDegguyM 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet select -T -t -v '//a[@class="postlink"]/@href' -n

  https://forums.raspberrypi.com/download/file.php?id=86753
  https://web.archive.org/web/20190824162104/https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/download/file.php?id=62517&sid=907ab04af81e19ad758c5bcf8ebdca32
```

I'm assuming you want the first of these, so let's extract that one:

```
xmlstarlet format --html BDegguyM 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet select -T -t -v '//dl[@class="file"]//a[@class="postlink"]/@href' -n

  https://forums.raspberrypi.com/download/file.php?id=86753
```

If you want just the part starting with `/download` you can strip that off easily

```
xmlstarlet format --html BDegguyM 2>/dev/null |
    xmlstarlet select -T -t -v '//dl[@class="file"]//a[@class="postlink"]/@href' -n |
    sed -E 's!^https?://[^/]+!!'

  /download/file.php?id=86753
```

If you really want to use `grep` instead of the right tool for the job, this will return the same result:

```
grep -Po 'https?://[^/]+\K/download/file.php\?id=\d+' BDegguyM

  /download/file.php?id=86753
```

Comment: Personally, I dislike backslash on principle -- too hard to use where a pattern may be parsed twice. I use a single-character class like `[.]` `[?]` and `[/]`.

Comment: @Seamus it works with the example you've shown us. If it doesn't match in your true source then the true source doesn't contain the text you have provided. Can you provide a reference to the actual web page? Or post the actual web page (unedited, untouched) somewhere accessible?

Comment: @Seamus I've made no mistake here. I've re-read your question, re-looked at the real HTML (as distinct from the incorrect version posted in your question), and offered an appropriate solution

Comment: @Seamus then I'm thoroughly puzzled. "_Following is the string I am trying to find (from the webpage): `./download/file.php?id=86753`_" and the subsequent statement too. This is what people including me used as the starting point for their answers. I don't see how this can mean anything other than that you're looking to match a string that starts with a dot. This is the cause of all the problems you are having because that dot does not exist in the webpage

Comment: @Seamus I've offered a solution using xmlstarlet. I've also offered a working solution using grep. I've retracted nothing. Take it or leave it as you will

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question in your subject line:

> Why does grep ignore the leading '.'?

is simply - it doesn't.

Using the 2 sample input lines you provided together in 1 file:

```
$ cat dlfile.html
href="./download/file.php?id=86753"
href="https://web.archive.org/web/20190824162104/https://www.somewhere.com/forums/download/file.php?id=62517&amp;sid=907ab04af81e19ad758c5bcf8ebdca32"
```

and just removing the undesirable (probably harmless but definitely relying on undefined behavior per POSIX) backslashes before the `/`s then running the 2 `grep` commands in your question:

```
$ grep -Eo '\./download/file\.php\?id=[0-9]+' dlfile.html
./download/file.php?id=86753

$ grep -Eo '/download/file\.php\?id=[0-9]+' dlfile.html
/download/file.php?id=86753
/download/file.php?id=62517
```

The first `grep`, which includes a leading `.`, only matches the string from the input that has a leading `.` while the second `grep`, which does not include a leading `.`, unsurprisingly matches 2 strings from the input that do not start with a `.`.

Regarding your comment about the first `grep` above:

> But this finds nothing in the html file.

then either:

1. The grep command in your question is not the same as the one you're actually using or
2. The real html file does not contain the strings you provided for us to use as sample input

so there's really nothing we can do to help you debug a command you're using to parse some input when either we don't know what your command looks like or we don't know what your input looks like.

Answer (score -1):

Works fine here if I change `\/` to plain `/`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/sh

printf 'href="%s"\n' \
       './download/file.php?id=86753' \
       'elsewhere/download/file.php?id=86753' |
    grep -oE '\./download/file\.php\?id=[0-9]+'
```

Output:

```
./download/file.php?id=86753
```

You might also consider adding `\B` at the beginning and `\b` at the end for better rejection of unwanted near-misses.

Comment: Same output if I use Bash as interpreter, too (unsurprisingly)

Comment: In that case, please provide some sample input in the question.

Comment: Add a sample _to the question_ - links are unreliable.